# Swing JComboBox weird behavior

Tags: java, windows, swing, jcombobox

I observe the following behavior (on the Windows 7 platform) :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Main extends JFrame{   
    JPanel p;
    JComboBox<String> l;
    JLabel title;
    public static void main(String[] arg){
      Main m = new Main();
      m.setVisible(true);
      m.setSize(400,400);
      m.p = new JPanel();
      //m.l = new JComboBox<String>();
      m.title = new JLabel("HELLO"); 
      m.p.add(m.title);
      m.setContentPane(m.p);
      }
}
```

Displays `HELLO`, but if I uncomment the line that instantiates the `JComboBox`, it won't display anything. What could cause that? Are you able to reproduce the bug?

Comment: Move `m.setVisible(true);` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I just found the answer, I should run pack on the JFrame, I have forgotten that ;(

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer, to clarify your question as answered

Comment: Your code should also run in the EDT. Anything else is asking for trouble

Comment: @HarryJoy could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @lc2817 : you can see my answer now.

Comment: @JensSchauder : See my answer, Have I explained your comment well or you want to say something else?

Comment: @Harry Joy: Now it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from my comment:

> Move `m.setVisible(true);` at the end.

Another comment from ***Jens Schauder***:

> Your code should also run in the EDT. Anything else is asking for
>   trouble

May be he wants to tell something like this:

Everything dealing with Swing components, including there construction [must run in the EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). If it doesn't it is broken, although you might not notice it.

For that you may move your logic from main method to constructor of class and call constructor as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
```

You can also write logic in some other method then constructor.